# How to print separator for all fields in join utility?

Tags: linux, join

For example:

file a:

```
Tom:black
Lily:pink
```

file b:

```
Tom:big
Kate:small
```

And, the result:

```
join -t: a1 a b
```

Got:

```
Tom:black:big
Lily:pink
```

But what I want is:

```
Tom:black:big
Lily::pink
```

i.e. The colon in the last line is missing, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think you'd want the fields to be in a consistent position. If so then one of these would work using only one invocation of `join` and no `sed`:

```
$ join -t: -a1 -o 1.1,1.2,2.2 a b
Tom:black:big
Lily:pink:
$ join -t: -a1 -o 1.1,2.2,1.2 a b
Tom:big:black
Lily::pink
```

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is expected per `man join`:

```
   -a FILENUM
          print unpairable lines coming from file FILENUM, where FILENUM is 1 or 2, corresponding to FILE1 or FILE2
```

You can do it in two passes like this:

```
join -t: a b && join -t: -v1 a b|sed 's/:/::/'
```

or something along those lines.